# 'Top Searches' or 'Top Queries' naming in an application for marketing people

Tags: search, user-expectation, research

I was wondering what everyones thoughts were on the naming for a search engine analytics application where it's technically correct to use the term 'querying' rather than the term 'searching'?

Personally, I prefer 'searches' rather than 'queries' as it's 2015 and I  think that search is a common word we have adapted over the years in most households as the internet has grown up, we don't go querying the internet...

This app is geared towards marketing people. So could you imagine them telling their clients 'there was a 33% increase in querying on the website' opposed to 'there was a 33% increase in searches on the website'. Sounds like people are getting up to no good I reckon!

What are your thoughts on the topic?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider "Querying" to be more of a technical term as opposed to a human friendly term. "Searching" has the advantage of being a simpler word for non-native English speakers to understand.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most frequent complaints about search is that it is not precise enough. Properly written queries, on the other hand, are completely precise. A query will give you exactly the result you ask for. Exactly what you asked for, which may or not be exactly what you want. The hardest part of a query is asking the right question.

Search, on the other hand, is not precise. A dumb search just gives you a randomly ordered list of items in which your search term occurs. A smart search will provide you a ranked list of items that are strongly related to the search terms you entered, even if they do not match the exactly. This means that even though some of the results will doubtless be unrelated, and sometimes absurd, there is a very good chance that there is data you can use pretty high up in those results, even if you didn’t ask quite the right question. And there may well be relevant data you didn’t even think to ask for.

Being smart in this way is a key benefit of search. Queries cannot be smart. Queries must always give you exactly what you asked for. There can be no tolerance for serendipity in query results. Search can be smart, but query must be dumb and strictly obedient.

**after going through you will have better idea**

I vote for '**Search**'

Reference: http://everypageispageone.com/2011/07/13/search-vs-query/

Answer (score 1):

The words have a totally different meaning actually, and using queries to talk about searches, would make it look like 'googling' is actually 'finding'.

When you search for something, you have some sense of what it is your are looking for, with querying you can go ahead and say that you will accept what you get as true. In that respect, for a database management system, you are allowed to display the *amount of queries*, as what is returned is true. This is because all that data is stored in a structured way, so you can easily look it up and you know that the question will give you an answer (even if that answer is *nil*).

For a site like google, you'd definitly use *amount of searches*, although the values returned are queried and thus not wrong, the *user* has to sift through the data to find the thing he was looking for, probably going back and forth a few times to narrow it down. This because of the unstructured nature of *the internet* and its content.

In my opinion, I'd simply go for 'searches', as marketeers are more likely to talk to actual people who don't, exactly know what they want (and will *search* for the product that best matches their needs and constraints).

sources:

- http://everypageispageone.com/2011/07/13/search-vs-query/

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! 
Search is obviously the better word to use.
but if the requirement says you to edit so you can also write something like "Total queries increased by 40%" 
"Queries increased by 40%"
"write your query"
"Looking for results for your query"